# Does ‘the officials’ mean what I want in this context?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> The country’s technological advances are often trumpeted by **the**
> **officials** as a cause of pride.

By ‘the officials’ I mean the administration, the governors, relevant people in the government, or the people in power in the country.

Is ‘the officials’ used in that sense?
Should I replace it by ‘**the authorities**’ maybe? Or maybe there is some other suggestions?

Comment: It does not mean that in general. It is very vague. I may take it to mean UN or ISO or IEEE who have officials looking into Scientific Progress by various countries & ranking that yearly. You may use it in which-ever way you want. You might even include the list in Parenthesis to elaborate your meaning. You could also use that list earlier [ Eg "Admin & governors & ... have always encouraged Science & Technology through various Events" ] & then use "these officials" to refer to that list. You should be Explicit about the meaning if that is what you want. If you want vagueness, then it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I recommend that you use **the authorities** instead. See the definition with a blue background [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/authority).